# Searching (x,y) pair in sequence

Tags: python, regex

I would like to find match (x,y) in string.
Is the following seem good ?

Or better alternative you can suggest. Please note that between (x,y) pairs several white spaces or commas may exists in mystring.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import re
mystring="(3,4) , (2, 4),(5,4), (2,3), "

tmp= re.findall(r'\(\d+,\d\)+', mystring)
print tmp

for i, v in enumerate(tmp):
    if v =="(5,4)":
        print "match found"
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you think will happen with that regex for the `(2, 4)` where there is a space? It also won't match `(2,10)` because the 2nd number is two digits long.

Comment: Thanks I think for spacing part mystring=re.sub(r'\s', '', mystring) can be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not search for the pair you want? Also, you can use \s to match whitespace.

```
import re

def find_pair(x, y, mystring):
    return re.findall(r'\(\s*?%d,\s*?%d\s*?\)+' % (x, y), mystring);

print find_pair(2, 4, "(3,4) , (2,   4),(5,4), (2,3), ")
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
re.findall(r'\(\d+,\d\)+', mystring)
```

Use

```
re.findall(r'\(5,4\)', mystring)
```

and it will only find the pair you want

Answer (score 2):

No regex needed:

```
ast.literal_eval(mystring).count((5,4))
```

or

```
if (5,4) in ast.literal_eval(mystring):
    print('Found!')
```

Comment: what is ast ? let me know pls